# Read text in console, created from other sources

Tags: c#, console-application

The goal of my application is to read the output from other executables which write their output into the console. Here I have only two extern .exe's running.
Those two Tasks are starting the external executables which will write into the console.
The executables are started with the `Process` Class.

```
Process startInfo = new Process();
startInfo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

The output is also redirected and I can see those two outputs in my main console of the .NetCore 3.1 Console application.

```
var t1 = new Task(() => ZilMiner.Start(),
    prog2CcTkSrc.Token,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

var t2 = new Task(() => VtcMiner.Start(),
    prog1CcTkSrc.Token,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
while (true)
{
   var text = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Since some programms are writing into my Console, I should run `Console.ReadLine()` and see those states from the other sources correct?

Unfortunately this is not possible with my setup. How can I manage to read the outputs generated from other programms in the console applications console?

Thanks!